# Запятая, тире или единый знак в БСП?

Tags: запятые, тире, бсп

Из художественной литературы:

*А вдруг провокация какая? Выборы ж скоро… Вообще-то я тебя по этому поводу и пригласил. *Мои сыскари ничего объяснить **не могут(?) бестолочи, а не сыскари,** уровень не тот… **им я тоже жалование урежу**.**

Здесь  четыре предикативные основы. Какой знак лучше подойдет? Или как-то еще можно записать это предложение?

Answer (score 1):

В двух источниках знак **был разный (**запятая и единый знак**):**

(1) *Мои сыскари ничего объяснить не могут, **бестолочи, а не сыскари, уровень не тот**… им я тоже жалование урежу.*

(2) *Мои сыскари ничего объяснить не могут, — **бестолочи, а не сыскари, уровень не тот…** им я тоже жалование урежу.*

Но во второй части **многоточие**. Наверное, этот знак сильнее (пауза больше).  Тогда лучше поставить **тире:**

(3) *Мои сыскари ничего объяснить не могут — бестолочи, а не сыскари, уровень не тот… **им я тоже жалование урежу.***

Comment: Да, просто тире лучше.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. А как вы объясняете?

Comment: Тире присоединяет дополнит. ремарку: оценку и причину, почему не могут.

Comment: А многоточие?  Последняя часть тоже входит в предложение. Можно считать, что это граница между двумя блоками.

Comment: Блоки не блоки... не знаю, а многоточие показывает, что мысль об урезании пришла в момент речи.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Мне просто хотелось понять, как многоточие влияет на остальные знаки.